# Two dimensional array of lists c++

Tags: c++, arrays, list, structure

I have problem with two dimensional array of lists. I'm making list in structured then i'm connecting it with array.

```
class Game: parent, stan
{
public:
      static void Start();

private:
    struct lista_rodzicow
    {
        static std::list<parent> kolejka;
    };

    static lista_rodzicow parent[10][10];
```

Here is my Parent.h header (not whole of course):

```
class parent
{   
public:
int x, y, strona, combo;

    parent();
    parent(int x, int y, int s, int c):x(x), y(y), strona(s), combo(c)
    {
    }
```

And method I have problems with:

```
bool Game::CzyBylem(int x, int y)
{
    for (std::list<parent>::iterator it = parent[x][y].kolejka.begin(); it != board[x][y].kolejka.end(); ++it)
    {
        if( it->x == x && it->y == y )
            return true;
    }
}
```

What I need is two dimension array with list (or queue) linked to it so eg. in element [3][4] I can add few different classes like (a, b, c, d).

Completely example:

```
[0][0] - (a, b, c, d), (a2, b2, c2, d2)

[0][1] - empty

[1][0] - (a3, b3, c3, d3)

[1][1] - (a4, b4, c4, d4), (a5, b5, c5, d5)
```

Erorrs i get:

```
Error   15  error C2923: 'std::list' : 'parent' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

Error   16  error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'  

Error   18  error C2228: left of '.end' must have class/struct/union    

Error   19  error C2839: invalid return type 'int *' for overloaded 'operator ->'   

Error   20  error C2039: 'x' : is not a member of 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'
```

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have `parent` as the class and a `parent` as a member of `Game`.
try define the member as `parent_`

Comment: I've changed static lista_rodzicow parent[10][10]; too lista_rodzicow _parent[10][10]; and parent[x][y].kolejka.begin() too _parent[x][y].kolejka.begin() etc. Now i get error Error 27 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::list<class parent,class std::allocator<class parent> > Game::lista_rodzicow::kolejka" (?kolejka@lista_rodzicow@Game@@2V?$list@Vparent@@V?$allocator@Vparent@@@std@@@std@@A)

Comment: remove static from kolejka and _parent, as this is causing your linking problems, or you need to instantiate them in a .cpp file.

Comment: You have to provide a definition outside the for static members. In this case, in one of your cpp files, `static Game::lista_rodzicow Game::_parent[10][10];`